# is this sentence from "baby honey(the Pastel's song),an example of good english grammar

Tags: lyrics, optional-that

> There is magic in her beautiful eyes
>   Justify the tears I’ve cried

found this sentence in the pastel's song" baby honey " ,I know that songs are not always the best example of "good grammar" but the sentence I think should be

> There is magic in her beautiful eyes
>    **That**  Justify the tears I’ve cried

I know in some sentences that is not necessary : is it the case ? Or is it another reason

here are the final lines of the song:

> There is magic in her fingertip
>   There is magic in the lips I kiss
>   There is magic in her beautiful eyes
>   Justify the tears I’ve cried

i think he gave all the reasons justifying the tears he has cried I don't think it is an independant sentence

Comment: Please use capital letters for names of songs, and bands, etc. Also, please use some punctuation, like lines of the song on separate lines.

Comment: The second line could easily be interpreted as a separate, independent clause (its own complete sentence): in this case, an imperative sentence. If so, your suggestion would change the meaning entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would interpret the second line "Justify..." as an independent clause and separate sentence. It is written using the imperative, and meaning "give a reason for me crying (because you are so beautiful etc.)". In this case, the grammar is good, but the meaning secondary

It could also be present indicative (meaning "You justify ....") with the subject removed for the sake of the song. Or it could be a relative clause with the pronoun removed. In these cases, the grammar would be incorrect, even if the meaning would make more sense.

As you say, songs can be fun to sing along to, and can help with vocabulary and pronuciation, but aren't much use as examples of clear grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret this as:

> There is magic in her beautiful eyes / 
>   [that] justif[ies] the tears I’ve cried.

shortened for meter. But it could be taken as an imperative form.

Honestly, expecting fully correct grammar from a song is not quite realistic.